# Reading .txt file for specific data and storing into sql fields

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm In the process of trying to understand Python and need help on how I will read a text file containing massive amounts of data, take specific information that is needed, and store it into database.

```
*-------------------------------------------*                                                                                        
* xxxxxxxxxxxx STARTED AT 2017-06-07-21.32.43.                                                                                  
*-------------------------------------------*                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
******* D I S P L A Y ************                                                                                  
*                                                 *                                                                                  
*REC READ     =  56,813                                                                                                   
*REC WRITTEN  =  56,813                                                                                                   
*CALLS   =     617                                                                                                   
*FOUND   =     963                                                                                                   
*NOT FND =         54                                                                                                   
*FOUND   =     4963                                                                                                   
*NOT FND =       0                                                                                                   
*SYS   =           1                                                                                                   
*SYS   =     462                                                                                                   
*--------------------------------------------*                                                                                       
* xxxxxxxxxxxx COMPLETED AT 2017-06-07-21.35                                                                                  
*--------------------------------------------*
```

```
    with open(fname) as f:
content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

My idea: From my understanding should I approach this by reading the .txt line by line, storing it into an array somehow, then using an if statement to test to see if the value in the indexes are true for example (Rec read, written) etc. How will I get the values next to it?...
(Just an idea, this might be completely wrong)

UPDATE: Using the code below, I'm able to read all the line and get the correct information that is needed. The Keywords get stored in line[0] and the values get stored in line[1]. I am now trying to append each value into a list so I can run a query on the list and add it to the correct fields in my access database. Right now when I print a list it only shows me one value rather then the others. My original file have multiple values paired with the same data. In other words there is multiple "Rec Read".

```
   file = open(r"C:\Users\cqt7wny\Desktop\joblogs.txt")

rec_read = []
rec_written = []
calls = []


for line in file:
   if "REC READ" in line: #This if statement looks through the line
     line = line.split("=") #This makes the line two items in a list
     rec_read.append(line[1])

   if "REC WRITTEN" in line:
       line = line.split("=")
       rec_written.append(line[1])
   if "CC01 CALLS" in line:
       line = line.split("=")
       calls.append(line[1])

print(rec_read)
```

The output:

```
['   7,558,265
```

What I want:

```
[7558265,324322,22232,etc]
```

Comment: show us your attempt before asking a question

Comment: @depperm added .. stuck after that

Comment: You need to fix your indentation to accurately match what you are actually running. As it stands, the code you've provided here would throw `IndentationError` and `SyntaxError`s. The easiest way is to copy from your text-editor, paste into your question, then highlight the code and press ctrl-k and it will format it for you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very helpful man thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

You have a good theoretical approach. Here's some code to help you get started, but you will have to change it to match your needs.

To open a file with Python:

`file = open('filename.txt')`

To iterate through the file line by line:

```
for line in file:
   if "REC READ" in line: #This if statement looks through the line
     line = line.split("=") #This makes the line two items in a list
     print(line[0])
```

This for statement can also be made into a while loop if necessary. More information about looking through files in python can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

I do not know what type of database you want to implement (there are several kinds for different purposes). A common one is postgresql, which is accessed through python by the psycopg2 driver for Python ([psycopg2 install info here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2)).

You can then start working on the database in python:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=url.path[1:],user=url.username,password=url.password,host=url.hostname,port=url.port)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE tablename (col1, col2, col3)""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""", (item1, item2, item3))
conn.commit()
```

Hope this can help you get started. Keep trying different things, then post your questions or cool things you find along the way to stackoverflow!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you!. Using this would it be best to now make an empty array of the index I need and append the values to each specific array.

Comment: @TenkorangDarko the data structure that corresponds to python `[]` is a *list*, not an array, and as such, making an empty `list` and `.append`ing to is is the typical way to do things. Note, the underlying implementation of `list` is an automatically-resizing arraylist with amortized constant-time `.append` performance, so it's designed to work that way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is exactly what I did. The text file I'm working with have multiple versions of the same "Rec Read". When I do print(line[1]) it lists all the corresponding values. I'v now made a list and when I append it within the for statement, only 1 value is getting saved.

Comment: @TenkorangDarko you need to elaborate on the issues you are encountering in the original question itself *with details like the exact code you are using and you inputs/outputs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga added